# Formatting on SmarGWT FloatItem

Tags: java, smartgwt

I want to apply a formatter on a FloatItem from SmartGWT. The FloatItem should fail validation if a "," is entered.

```
FloatItem floatItem = new FloatItem("name", "title");
floatItem.setFormat("##0.###");
```

This FloatItem will still automatically remove the "," if it is entered. In other words, no thousands separator should be allowed in this field. Adding

```
floatItem.setType(FieldType.LOCALEFLOAT.getValue());
```

to the FloatItem, will work for me locally, but this will not work for everybody. Is there a way to correctly apply a number format to the FloatItem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the basic float type if you don't want locale specific number formatting to be applied. For example:

```
FloatItem floatItem = new FloatItem("name", "title");
floatItem.setType(FieldType.FLOAT.getValue());
```

Also, you can apply your own validator and keyPressFilter, which will completely stop users typing in anything besides 0-9 and .

```
RegExpValidator validator = new RegExpValidator(); 
validator.setExpression("^[0-9.]*$");
floatItem.setValidators(validator);
floatItem.setKeyPressFilter("^[0-9.]*$");
```

I think just using the correct FieldType.FLOAT will give you the validation that you want.